# visual similarity of images in java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, image-segmentation, feature-extraction

Hi I have a project which related to the content based image retrieval. I have a doubt about what criteria should be taken for this project.when I searched this there I got two methods Feature extraction and  image segmentation and region manipulation. Which method is more efficient?

Comment: You would do this the same way in Swing is in AWT or a servlet.  Swing tag removed in favor of 4 more closely related tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither.    Answer to this question will require some researrch on yor side. Image recognition is usually done via following steps

- some preprocessing  to filter out unnecessary features ( depends on context, for text recognition you would binarise  images , for face recognition may be made them grayscale... )
- finding region of interest ( in case of text recognition you would try to locate text lines / glyphs , in case of faces apply some haar cascade to find where faces are - also depends on your image set )
- feature extraction ( there is a ton of different methods,  for some shapes invariant moments like Hu are good solution, for faces you could get better results with Zernike moments - they are based on polar coordinates )
- matching ( easier part:  you have got some feature vector,   typically doubles, and now you have to match it to other feature vector / class of vectors -  here you go with cluster analysis, there are also different techniques )

You may see it all together in action in JavaOCR project ( text recognition for android )  - but please compile it from source as release is pretty old ):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/